# Как обратится к объектам ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, queryset

Имеется Django форма ManyToManyFields:

```
class A(models.Model):
    package = models.ManyToManyField(Package)
```

ссылается она на вот такую модель

```
class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Пакет', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

Вид в админке -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытках обратится к ней через консоль
`objects.all()/objects.filter/values_list` получаю `None`

либо вывод в админ панели через

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.package.name)
```

тоже `None`

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какой способ можно взаимодействовать с выбранными элементами, чтоб получить хоть какую-то информацию помимо None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации есть [целый раздел](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) посвящённый M2M-отношениями:

```
a = A.objects.last()
for p in a.package.all():
    print(p.name)
```

Comment: К сожалению, Ваш вариант не помогает :(  `'A' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: Прошелся циклом по `a.package.all():` выводя `a` без `name`,  и обнаружил что вконце все равно написано None

Comment: Я просто опечатался. Исправил, проверьте.